# The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested

Tags: caml, csom

I am getting below error on the **second request**. Strange thing is its not occurring on **first request**.

*The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.*

```
function RequestSP(siteUrl, listTitle, xmlCamlQuery, viewFields) {
    debugger;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(xmlCamlQuery);

    this.spListItemCollection = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    var includeFields = JoinViewFieldsByComma(viewFields);
    console.log(includeFields);
    clientContext.load(spListItemCollection, "Include(" + includeFields + ")");

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = spListItemCollection.getEnumerator();//ERROR

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        for (var index in this.ViewFields) {
            var internalName = this.ViewFields[index][0];
            listItemInfo += "\n" + internalName + ": " + oListItem.get_item(internalName);
        }
    }

    console.log("Success...");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**EDIT**

So one thing i did not mention that I was loading SPRuntime with every request and I updated it with below which worked for me.

```
var spRuntimeLoaded = false;
if (spRuntimeLoaded) {
    RequestSP(siteUrl, listTitle, xmlCamlQuery, viewFields);
}
else {
    var scriptbase = siteUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                    function () {
                        spRuntimeLoaded = true;
                        RequestSP(siteUrl, listTitle, xmlCamlQuery, viewFields);

                    }
            );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other code on the page that would be overwriting the `spListItemCollection` variable?

You can protect against global variable naming collisions by using an anonymous inline function in place of `onQuerySucceeded`, then using a locally-scoped variable for `spListItemCollection` (using `var spListItemCollection = ...` instead of `this.spListItemCollection = ...`).

```
function RequestSP(siteUrl, listTitle, xmlCamlQuery, viewFields) {
    debugger;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(xmlCamlQuery);
    /* use a locally-scoped variable for spListItemCollection: */
    var spListItemCollection = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(spListItemCollection, "Include(" + includeFields + ")");
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
        debugger;
        var listItemInfo = '';
        var listItemEnumerator = spListItemCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            for (var index in this.ViewFields) {
                var internalName = this.ViewFields[index][0];
                listItemInfo += "\n" + internalName + ": " + oListItem.get_item(internalName);
            }
        }
        console.log("Success...");
    }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i found the issue. The issue was I was loading SPRuntime with every request so it was working for the first time and failed with second request.